# Reducing code duplication between operator= and the copy constructor

Tags: c++, dry, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a class that requires a non-default copy constructor and assignment operator (it contains lists of pointers).  Is there any general way to reduce the code duplication between the copy constructor and the assignment operator?

Comment: i think you should be able to call the copy constructor inside the operator=

Comment: Some answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457842/is-this-good-code-copy-ctor-operator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no "general way" for writing custom copy constructors and assignment operators that works in all cases. But there's an idiom called "copy-&-swap":

```
 class myclass
 {
    ...
 public:
    myclass(myclass const&);

    void swap(myclass & with);

    myclass& operator=(myclass copy) {
        this->swap(copy);
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

It's useful in many (but not all) situations. Sometimes you can do better. A vector or a string could have a better assignment which reuses allocated storage if it was large enough.

Comment: +1 - good and terse summary of copy-swap i think. Also good idea about reusing storage.

Comment: You might want to point out the subtlety here between your operator= and the more standard const myclass& operator=(const myclass& other);

Comment: The swap() should probably marked as nothrow. Ditto on Bills comment. Some more explnation would be nice.

Comment: Also note that:
> swap ought to be a free function 'void swap(myclass&, myclass&)'
> you still have to enumerate all your attributes in swap, instead of enumerating them in the assignment operator

Comment: How does this prevents code duplication since `swap` must be specialized?

Comment: It's not exactly "code duplication" since initialization is not the same as assignment. But Matthieu is right. You obviously have to "enumerate" the members in your swap function. I see no way around this unless you implement your copy ctor in terms of default constructed members + assignment. But in my opinion, this isn't a good solution. Ideally, you don't have to write copy ctor and assignment yourself and ideally, you don't have classes with 99 members.

Comment: operator=()'s arguments should always be const.

Comment: Is there anything special about `this->swap(copy)` here, or would `swap(copy)` also work?

Comment: @kevinarpe: Nothing special. `swap(copy)` also works. Sometimes I write `this->` to make it more explicit that it's a data member or member function.

Answer (score 17):

Factor out the common code to a private member function. A simple (rather contrived) example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(const char* n)
  {
    name = new char[20];
    strcpy(name, n);
  }

  ~Test()
  {
    delete[] name;
  }

  // Copy constructor
  Test(const Test& t)
  {
    std::cout << "In copy constructor.\n";
    MakeDeepCopy(t);
  }

  // Assignment operator
  const Test& operator=(const Test& t)
  {
    std::cout << "In assignment operator.\n";
    MakeDeepCopy(t);
  }

  const char* get_name() const { return name; }

private:
  // Common function where the actual copying happens.
  void MakeDeepCopy(const Test& t)
  {        
    strcpy(name, t.name);
  }

private:
  char* name;
};

int
main()
{
  Test t("vijay");
  Test t2(t); // Calls copy constructor.
  Test t3(""); 
  t3 = t2; // Calls the assignment operator.

  std::cout << t.get_name() << ", " << t2.get_name() << ", " << t3.get_name() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is almost always the best way to handle code duplication within a class.

Comment: memory leak! MakeDeepCopy ignores the possibility of name already pointing to allocated memory.

Comment: But it's a pity that the copy constructor cannot use member initializers, this way...

Comment: Note that `t2 = t2` won't work with the assignment operator as written. (You care about this if you want to sort an array of them, for example.)

Comment: To add a little more: I don't think reuse is applicable. There's a difference between creating a new object and just assigning to it. In the cases where simple member-wise assignment is sufficient, custom copy constructors and assignment operators are not needed. In case you have to do something more advanced (i.e. managing allocated memory) the similarity between copy and assignment is near zero.

Comment: @sellibitze The only point of the example is to show that whatever behavior that is common to both copy constructor and the assignment operator should be moved to a common function. Ignore all other shortcomings of the code.

Comment: @Vijay: but now you forgot to initialize "name" for copy construction which sort of proves my point. When explicit resource management is involved copy construction and copy assignment do different things. The possibility of reuse is minimal.

Comment: sir, I don't quite get it, but your operator= doesn't return anything, does it?

Answer (score 8):

```
My &My::operator = (My temp)  // thanks, sellibitze
{
    swap (*this, temp);
    return *this;
}
```

and implement a specialised `std::swap<> (My &, My &)`.

Comment: This is now how copy-&-swap should look like. You're explicitly creating a copy which otherwise may be elided. There's a great article about that here: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: As Dave notices, alexandrescu found about about this 6 years ago already: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403855 . Interesting read too!

Comment: errm, incidentally the poster is also called Dave. I'm sorry about the confusion - i meant the Dave Abrahams of cpp-next :)

Comment: That Alexandrescu article was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out by quite a few posters, having operator= create a new
object with the copy constructor and then use swap is the common technique used to not have to replicate code in operator=.

That said, I want to point out some a pro and a con of this technique to help you decide whether it is appropriate.

Pro - exception safety

If your object has resource requirements that could cause a throw and assuming that swap will not throw, this technique provides the strong guarantee of exception safety (either the object being assigned to has taken on the value of the other object or it is unchanged).

Con - resource footprint

An issue with this technique is that it requires a complete new object to be created before the old one is released.  If your object requires a lot of resources, this can be a problem.