# The copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor, operators, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

If I override `operator=` will the copy constructor automatically use the new operator? Similarly, if I define a copy constructor, will `operator=` automatically 'inherit' the behavior from the copy constructor?

Comment: Look at the this links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457842/is-this-good-code-copy-ctor-operator & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477145/reducing-code-duplication-between-operator-and-the-copy-constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No, they are different operators.

The copy constructor is for creating a new object. It copies an existing object to a newly constructed object.The copy constructor is used to initialize a new instance from an old
instance. It is not necessarily called when passing variables by value into functions
or as return values out of functions.

The assignment operator is to deal with an already existing object. The assignment operator is used to change an existing instance to have
the same values as the rvalue, which means that the instance has to be
destroyed and re-initialized if it has internal dynamic memory.

Useful link :

- [Copy Constructors, Assignment Operators, and More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163742.aspx)
- [Copy constructor and = operator overload in C++: is a common function possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734628/copy-constructor-and-operator-overload-in-c-is-a-common-function-possible)

Comment: @Prasoon, I don't quite understand, when passing variables by value into functions or as return values out of functions, why copy-constructor might not be called? And what's RVO?

Comment: @Alcottreturn value optimization

Comment: There is also copy elision, which does the same for function parameters

Answer (score 13):

No. Unless you define a copy ctor, a default will be generated (if needed). Unless you define an operator=, a default will be generated (if needed). They do not use each other, and you can change them independently.

Answer (score 6):

No. They are different objects.

If your concern is code duplication between copy constructor and assignment operator, consider the following idiom, named [**copy and swap**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap) :

```
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(const MyClass&); // Implement copy logic here
    void swap(MyClass&) throw(); // Implement a lightweight swap here (eg. swap pointers)

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass x)
    {
        x.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This way, the `operator=` will use the copy constructor to build a new object, which will get exchanged with `*this` and released (with the old `this` inside) at function exit.

Comment: by referring to the copy-and-swap idiom, do you imply that it's not a good practice to call operator= in copy-ctor or vice versa?

Comment: @Alcott: You don't call the operator= in the copy constructor, you do it the other way around, like I show.

Comment: Why is your assignment operator not taking a const reference ?

Comment: @JohanBoule: This is explained in the wikipedia link in my answer, and also in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143787/what-is-copy-elision-and-how-does-it-optimize-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 1):

No.

And definitely have a look at [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
(or [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x) when taking rvalues into account)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following C++ program.
**Note**: My "Vector" class not the one from the standard library.
**My "Vector" class interface**:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
private:
    double* elem; // elem points to an array of sz doubles
    int sz;
public:
    Vector(int s);  // constructor: acquire resources
    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; }   // destructor: release resources
    Vector(const Vector& a);               // copy constructor
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& a);    // copy assignment operator
    double& operator[](int i){ return elem[i]; };
    int size() const {return sz;};
};
```

**My "Vector" class members implementation**:

```
Vector::Vector(int s)  // non-default constructor
{
    std::cout << "non-default constructor"<<std::endl;
    elem = {new double[s]};
    sz =s;
    for (int i=0; i!=s; ++i)      // initialize elements
        elem[i]=0;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& a)   // copy constructor
        :elem{new double[a.sz]},
         sz{a.sz}
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor"<<std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)    // copy elements
        elem[i] = a.elem[i];
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a)     // copy assignment operator
{
    std::cout << "copy assignment operator"<<std::endl;
    double* p = new double[a.sz];
    for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i)
        p[i] = a.elem[i];
    delete[] elem;         // delete old elements
    elem = p;
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
}

int main(){
    Vector v1(1);
    v1[0] = 1024;    // call non-default constructor
   
    Vector v2 = v1;   // call copy constructor  !!!!

    v2[0] = 1025;
    std::cout << "v2[0]=" << v2[0] << std::endl;

    Vector v3{10};  // call non-default constructor
    std::cout << "v3[0]=" << v3[0] << std::endl;

    v3 = v2;     // call copy assignment operator  !!!!
    std::cout << "v3[0]=" << v3[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Then, the program output:

```
non-default constructor
copy constructor
v2[0]=1025
non-default constructor
v3[0]=0
copy assignment operator
v3[0]=1025
```

**To wrap up**:

1. `Vector v2 = v1;` lead to  call copy constructor.
2. `v3 = v2;`   lead to  call copy assignment operator.

In  case 2, Object `v3` already exists (We have done: `Vector v3{10};`). There are two obvious differences between copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

- copy constructor NO NEED to delete old elements, it just `copy construct` a new object. (as it `Vector v2`)
- copy constructor NO NEED to return the `this` pointer.(Furthermore, all the constructor does not return a value).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same operator.