# how come invoking a constructor implicitly and invoking a constructor explicitly turns out to be same

Tags: c++, constructor

I am new to c++.
I was told that invoking a constructor internally or externally are same.
Why is assignment operation not involved in the case of invoking constructor explicitly?

```
Object A(3)                //implicit
Object A = Object(3);      //explicit
```

I think an object will get created when we do Object(3);
So how are these two things turn out to be same?

Comment: Because although it uses the assignment operator, it's not an assignment. It's a copy constructor call (which is allowed to be optimised away, and line 2 will likely do the exact same thing as line 1).

Comment: The two are semantically different, are likely to do exactly the same, and should have the same result regardless.

Comment: These are both explicit invoking of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368258/the-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator) for more on the subject, but assignment operator is invoked when you are dealing with an already existing object. You'll notice similar behaviour for copy constructors:

```
Object A;
// the following two lines will call the copy constructor 
// even if the assignment operator is defined.
Object B = A;
Object C(A);
```